# custom style action bar not working in android 4

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, android-support-library

For customizing my action bar I use code below in xml:

```
<style name="CustomActionbarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/customTab</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/title_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="customTab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bg_selector</item>
</style>
```

I have no problem using api level 10 but when I run my code in higher api devices, action bars are in their default theme. I use support library v7 in my project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update: as of [AppCompat version 21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), all API levels now use the non-prefixed style names so there is no longer a need to add the `android:` namespaced attributes.

**Now obsolete:** If you are using the support library v7 `ActionBar`, you need to declare your custom styles twice, once without the `android:` prefix (for <v11 support - this is what you have) and once with (for >=v11 support - you need to add this) as per the [Styling the Action Bar guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground7).

Comment: when I add android: I got error because my min sdk is 8 what should I do?

Comment: @MohamadGhafourian - was it a Lint error or a compilation error? If it was a Lint error, you can either ignore it (attributes that the system doesn't know about don't hurt anything) or move the `android:` versions to a `values-v11` version of your `styles.xml` file. If it was a compilation error, that is because your `targetSdkVersion` was less than v11, so you should increase that to the latest version you've tested with, as per  the [Supporting Different Devices guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#sdk-versions)

Comment: Thanks for showing the way. I figured an easier way. using 'tools:targetApi="11"' will fix the error.

Comment: Woot Woot! Thank you! I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Comment: @ianhanniballake link is broken :( Please update if you can. Thanks.

Comment: @Rachael - the only link that is broken is in the obsolete part of the answer - just follow the first part.