# Can someone please help me understand why this code is not turning the Android Action Bar yellow?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I followed the [Google's tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) for changing the color of the Action Bar and wrote the code shown below, but the Action Bar still shows up as per the Holo Light theme.

styles.xml:

```
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

Android Manifest:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.labside.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

The colors.xml has yellow defined as #FFFF00. Please let me know what I am doing wrong as this whole stuff about Action Bar styling with support for API level 8 is starting to get very confusing! As always, many thanks for all your help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What android version are you using? Take a look at this post: [custom style action bar not working in android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726865/custom-style-action-bar-not-working-in-android-4)

Following this post, you need to declare your custom style twice. It looks like you are missing the declaration with the `android:` prefix.

So I guess, you'll have to add:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/yellow</item>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I followed the post you shared and added the android:actionBarStyle, android:background items for APIs 11 and above using the 'tools:targetApi="11"' attribute. The color change now works on my Android 4.2 device.