# Button style working in Android 5 but not Android 4

Tags: android, styles, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I have a button style with a blue background that works fine in API 22, but the same button appears in dark grey without the applied style in Android 4. This is my style:

```
<style name="MyApp.Plain" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
      <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Button</item>
</style>


  <style name="MyApp.Widget.Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_blue</item>
      <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
      <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
      <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
   </style>
```

My btn_blue.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal_blue" android:state_enabled="true"/>

</selector>
```

and btn_normal_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#368ac6"
        android:startColor="#0e58a4" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

What could be the reason for this behavior and how can I fix this?

EDIT: This does not work with support v7:22.2.0, but does work with v7:21.0.3. I didn't change anything besides the dependency and changed AppCompatActivity to ActionBarActivity.

Possibly this is an Android bug.

Comment: show the drawable/btn_blue contents

Comment: Is there any chance you have separate folders for the API versions, and this style is only in one of them?

Comment: @mcAdam331: No, I only have one styles file.

Comment: Do all the other attributes work? Is it clickable? Is the text style bold in 4 also? Is it *only* failing on background?

Comment: It is clickable, however for some reason the text is all caps, not bold, but same color.

Comment: Added the code for btn_blue to my question

Comment: Added the parent of the button style. Maybe this is causing the problems?

Comment: I wonder if this Android bug has anything to do with it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160591 I am using v7:22.2.0 though

Comment: This does not work with support v7:22.2.0, but does work with v7:21.0.3. I didn't change anything besides the dependency and changed AppCompatActivity to ActionBarActivity.

Possibly this is an Android bug.

Comment: Might not fix the problem but since your App theme inherits Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar, you should inherit your buttonStyle from Widget.AppCompat.Button or Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `buttonStyle` instead of `android:buttonStyle`, since this is AppCompat attribute pre Lollipop, so it should be without android prefix.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, fixed my problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some layouts where the attributes are applied twice, with and without the Android prefix. Can you try this:

```
<style name="MyApp.Widget.Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_blue</item>
      <item name="background">@drawable/btn_blue</item>
      <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
      <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
      <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

I am currently trying to find where I saw this previously, and why it worked. Let me know if it did.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but unfortunately on API 10 still grey background for the button.

Comment: @barq I guess it was worth a shot. Can you post the btn_blue contents like Lucas asked? The problem may be in there, then.

Comment: @barq I found what I was thinking of, it related to the support library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726865/custom-style-action-bar-not-working-in-android-4 I am leaving my answer for now, in case I am able to edit it and help you after.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that question too. Unfortunately, this didn't work, at least not on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AppCompat:

```
    <style name="MyApp.Widget.Button" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_blue</item>
      ...
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work either, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you set the style to the button?

Comment: No, it is the general button style for the app so there should be no need. It works without doing that in Android 5.

Answer (score 0):

@Michał Kisiel answer is correct "Try `buttonStyle` instead of `android:buttonStyle`, since this is AppCompat attribute pre Lollipop, so it should be without android prefix."
I just want to **add** that if you for instance ***create a view programatically*** you should put android:buttonStyle and buttonStyle too, sample:

```
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/OrangeButton</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/OrangeButton</item>
```